# How to define a dependency between data patch and upgrade script

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade-script, declarative-schema

As described in the [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html) you can define data patch dependencies.

> To define a dependency in a patch, add the `method public static function getDependencies()` to the patch class and return the class names of the patches this patch depends on. The dependency can be in any module.

My goal is to make sure a upgrade script ran before a data patch.

Adding the upgrade script in the `getDependencies()` method won't work because it does not implement the `\Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchInterface`.

Is it somehow possible to require a upgrade script as dependency to make sure it ran before the data patch?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I have red that old scripts can be converted in data patch implementing Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface

Comment: That is a very good hint! Feel free to post an elaborate answer based on the PatchVersionInterface.